# USS memory mapping with malloc(s) in process

Tags: memory-management, uss

I am working on memory optimization for my process and trying to map the allocated mallocs (tracked through sigwinch) with the USS memory(libc_malloc) Problem is: USS lists showing pretty large allocations than what allocation has been called from libc through malloc.(not using mmap).
My question is:
1. How can i see where malloc size is converting to size shown in libc_malloc). at least the logical explanation that comes near to what i am seeing. At present there is huge gap.

2. Is there any gap in my understanding?? since there is huge gap in USS and actually allocated memory. will appreciate if you can give any references.

Comment: If I may ask, how do you track allocations with SIGWINCH?